# Adding a new column in dataframe and looking up values from matrix in R

Tags: r

Created a matrix named GroMatrix.

```
GroMatrix=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4)
```

I want to use this matrix as reference for entering data in a new column of my existing data frame by looking up data from two different columns of the same row to be treated as row number and column number of matrix. I was trying with following method but in vain.

```
Df$NewCol=GroMatrix[Df$Col1,Df$Col2]
```

Col1 and Col2 are two variables of Dataframe Df and both these columns are numeric (integers).
On running the above command, I am getting a number of new observations added to my dataframe namely NewCol[,1], NewCol[,2], and so on.
Need help .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to subset matrix through a matrix.

So, to subset matrix through matrix you have to convert your dataset into a matrix.  Use `as.matrix` for that. Moreover, subsetting matrix through a matrix gives us a vector. For more reading, please see [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#matrix-subsetting)

Let's suppose your reference cols in data frame are named `row` and `col`.  Just follow these steps

```r
Gromatrix <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8),byrow=TRUE,nrow=4)
set.seed(1)
df_samp <- data.frame(
  row = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE),
  col = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
df_samp$new_col <- Gromatrix[as.matrix(df_samp[, c('row', 'col')])]
df_samp
#>    row col new_col
#> 1    1   3       3
#> 2    4   3       6
#> 3    3   1       3
#> 4    1   5       5
#> 5    2   5       6
#> 6    1   2       2
#> 7    3   2       4
#> 8    3   1       3
#> 9    2   5       6
#> 10   2   5       6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Mr. Anil Goyal for your response.

Comment: @SaptarshiRoy please accept the answer if it served the purpose. Additionally you can upvote answers too.  Comments here are meant for discussion only

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal. The solution provided by you worked well and I could do the task with its help.